# What is gr:get:User?

Tags: facebook, request, rate-limiting

Our app got rate limited - and looking at the insights, it seems to be due to this call:

gr:get:User

However, there is little information as to what constitutes this call. For instance, does any call to the graph - regardless of user, access token (with or without) - count as a request? Or is it more specific than that.

Any information is much appreciated. Thank you!